# How can I steal things without getting caught?

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

I was poking my nose about the Alchemist's shop when I found a locked chest. Greedy little sneakthief that I am, I wasted no time in picking the lock in search of loots!

The guards, who were upstairs at the time, immediately rushed downstairs and tried to arrest me.

Is there some way to ensure my thievings don't get interrupted by psychic guards?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> To reliably steal, you need to get out of the guard's line of sight
>   and stay there for a while.

Your chance to be caught at thievery seems to correlate to the guard's awareness level of you. You can easily see your chance to fail as a percentage next to the item's name when you're about to loot it.

[image]

If the guard is in sight, you can also see how aware he is of you by entering stealth mode and looking at the icon over his head.

[image]
[image]

This means that a guard may not even be in the same room as you, but may notice you steal, simply because his "awareness" from when he last saw you hasn't worn off yet. His awareness will drop over time as you stay out of his sight. My experience is that the awareness level seems to drop for different guards at different rates... it was almost instantaneous for the guard in the alchemist's shop in Gorhart, but took longer for the guard in Shieldring Keep.

Comment: Hm. I don't remember a % chance in the demo. I'll have to check this out.

Comment: Do you know what happens if you get caught? Jail, fine, etc? I'd rather just know instead of finding out the hard way :)

Comment: @spugsley I haven't been caught yet, but I heard you get thrown in jail, where you can either try to break out or else serve your sentence (which costs you some xp).

Answer (score 0):

When guards are in sight and you've been noticed, all you have to do is relax and wait for the right time to strike your target.

Answer (score 0):

I have stolen almost everything that can be stolen :) I use my smoke bombs (stealth ability). If you use the smoke bomb, and become invisible, you can loot big crowds with 5% or less. I just hit a tavern at night and clear out half the town's pockets. ;)