# Why is my chance of theft discovery high even if a guard is nowhere near?

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I steal things without getting caught?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/48769/how-can-i-steal-things-without-getting-caught)

In Shieldring Keep, I have picked the lock on a side room chest. There is a patrolling guard who exits the room and walks far away, yet when I attempt to loot the chest, my chance of discovery is always above 90%. Why? What can I do to improve (lower) discovery chances?

I am playing rogue, bow/fae blade and wearing all light armor.

Comment: Duplicate? http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/48769/3062

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've noticed the sneak mechanic in *Kingdoms of Amalur: Reckoning* is a fickle mistress. From what I can tell, if *anyone* saw you in the vicinity at *any* point, even when you sneak they'll still be aware of your presence.

[image]

Even though I'm not in anyone's direct line of sight, they're still alert to my presence when sneaking. To remedy this, you can simply wait in that same spot for a short period of time. Their awareness will gradually decrease over time, resulting in:

[image]

**As that meter decreases, your chance of being caught while stealing will also decrease!**

Comment: Thank you, this was the problem. I had to simply wait longer for him to patrol back and forth for the "eye" to go down through the walls.

Comment: This actually makes sense. If a guard hears a muffled click just after he's seen a guy in a hood head upstairs, he's a little more likely to check it out...